# optionalChaning with recursion

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I need a function that takes as its first parameter an object, and as its second parameter a string to pass through to get the value. If any of the properties is not found, the function returns undefined.

I can do it with reduce.
but how can I do it with recursion? will it be faster with recursion?

```js
const obj = {a: {b: {c: {d: 'Hello'}}}}

function optionalChaining (obj, path) {
  // recursion solution

}
```

### expected result:

```
optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c"); // { d: 'Hello' }
optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c.d"); // Hello
optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c.d.e"); // undefined
optionalChaining(obj, "b.d.a"); // undefined
```

Comment: why empty string for empty property? what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I don't need it, thank you. Took it out of the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `recursion` in each iteration, by splitting the `path` and trying to find if the `key` exists in the object.

- **The first iteration.**

`obj` will be `{a: {b: {c: {d: 'Hello'}}}}` and `index` will be `0` so the key will be `a`

- **The second iteration.**

`obj` will be `{b: {c: {d: 'Hello'}}}` and `index` will be `1` so the key will be `b`

And so on, until the `obj` undefined or the `index` be more than `path` length after splitting the dot `.` to stop the `recursion`.

```js
const obj = {a: {b: {c: {d: 'Hello'}}}}

function optionalChaining (obj, path, index = 0) {

  if(obj === undefined) return
  if (path.split('.').length <= index) return obj

  return optionalChaining(obj[path.split('.')[index]], path, index + 1)
}

console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c")); // { d: 'Hello' }
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c.d")); // Hello
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c.d.e")); // undefined
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "b.d.a")); // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

With recursion you can do something like this.
Function has 4 lines of code and it doesn't need any kind of index tracing.

```js
const obj = {a: {b: {c: {d: 'Hello'}}}}

function optionalChaining (obj, path) {
  const [key, nextPath] = path.split(/\.(.*)/s);
  if (!obj[key]) return undefined;
  if (!nextPath) return obj[key];
  return optionalChaining(obj[key], nextPath);
}

console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c")); // { d: 'Hello' }
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c.d")); // Hello
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c.d.e")); // undefined
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "b.d.a")); // undefined
```

**Will it be faster with recursion?**
We didn't see your solution with `reduce` but the difference will probably be unrecognizable (it still has to iterate over each part of path).

Answer (score 1):

You could split the path and check if the path is empty.

```js
const
    optionalChaining = (object, path) => {
        const
            [key, ...rest] = path.split('.');

        return path
            ? optionalChaining(object?.[key], rest.join('.'))
            : object;
    },
    obj = { a: { b: { c: { d: 'Hello' } } } };

console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c")); // { d: 'Hello' }
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c.d")); // Hello
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "a.b.c.d.e")); // undefined
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "b.d.a")); // undefined
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, "")); // complete object
```